# Delete files based on name

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that archives files into a ZIP with the format "DAILY-yyyymmdd" and i would like to only keep 15 days worth of files. e.g. DAILY-20170405, DAILY-20170504.

I was wondering if there was a way to using forfile (or similar) to remove files based on the name (and not the date/time stamp) of the file? I cannot use the date/time stamp as sometimes these are corrupted and could be a few weeks behind/ahead.

I have used the following, but this uses the date/time stamp:
for /f "skip=15 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.7z') do ( del "%%F" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming scheme allows lexicographical sort on dates, so you can just reverse-sort by name (instead of the date):

```
for /f "skip=15 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-n *.7z') do ( del "%%F" )
```

Comment: Great thanks. Does this actually look at the date or just order them and skip the first 15 files? If the system misses 3 days, will it just keep the 15 most recent files?

Comment: Yeah, `/o-n` orders by name in descending order and `skip=15` skips 15 (most 'recent') items.